# C++ seems to ignore lines of code when i dont use the debugger

Tags: c++

Hello and i just want to mention i tried searching for this topic but didn't find anything, so here my question:

i wrote a small programm where i wanted to make a list with timestamps that gets updated. So i wrote a little class to handle everything about this. (i left out things that are not necessary)

Edit: also to mention, the actual function is in a .cpp file, this is the header with the added function, just for reference on what i actually wrote.

```
#pragma once
#include <chrono>
#include <map>

class TimeHandler
{
public:
    TimeHandler();
    ~TimeHandler();

    std::map<std::chrono::milliseconds, std::string> getTimeList();
    /*add a timepoint for the current time to the timelist*/
    void addTimePoint(std::string name);
    /*print the timelist*/
    void print();
private:
    std::map<std::chrono::milliseconds,std::string> timeList;
};

void TimeHandler::addTimePoint(std::string name)
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    timeList.insert( std::make_pair(ms, name) );
    //std::cout << "\n adding";
}
```

The class handles just time-events where i can add a description.

Now to my problem. I am giving a pointer of the object to other functions to call the addTimePoint-function at the start and the end of them. 
But not all time events are there. if i put a breakpoint in addTimePoint and debug, everything works fine, also if i add a std::cout after the insert).
But if i dont have the std::cout or use the debuger it will not put everything in the map.

If anyone could help me, i am at the end of any ideas where the problem seems to be.

and please dont judge me for my bad english, i am still learning.

Comment: If 2 insertions take place in the same milliseconds which is highly possible then the second one won't be inserted.

Comment: Probably your code is so fast that a lot of your labels end on the same milliseconds value in your map and as such your map overwrites the same bucket multiple times. Hence, you think values are "missing". Picard: "For a moment I thought you would betray me." Data: "I did consider that for 10E-9 nanoseconds. And that is a long time for an android." ;)

Comment: Are you in a multithread enviroment? If so maybe you need to protect timeList variable

Comment: just change your std::map<std::chrono::milliseconds,std::string> to a std::vector<std::pair<std::chrono::milliseconds,std::string>> and all your timePoints will be present.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto or into a ``std::map<std::chrono::milliseconds,std::vector<std:string> >`` so multiple strings can be stored in the same time bucket.

Comment: @BitTickler or into a `std::multimap<std::chrono::milliseconds, std::string>` so it... uh... looks nice or something.

Comment: Also what is the resolution of `std::chrono::system_clock` on your platform, 15ms or 50ms?  It might not be as granular as you think.

Comment: @uv239, please post the solution as an answer instead of editing it into the title and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, the answer was indeed, that the time it took was too short and therefore the second time couldnt be added because the timestamp was the same. (and a map can only store every key 1 time)

I am using a vector now :)